# How files from amazon S3 bucket will be indexed to my cloud organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coveo

After creating a bucket and giving credentials Access key Id and Secret key Id, i am facing issue 
"The provided Amazon S3 bucket URL does not exist or may contain typos."

Any solution to this.

Comment: What are you trying to do when this issue occurs?  Your question needs to be more complete.

Comment: I am trying to index the files(PDF,HTML,TEXT) from S3 bucket to coveo cloud organization

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider to use the 'edit' function to improve your question. Not all readers read all the comments to decide if they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the URL you are using when configuring your source is not valid. Did you follow this procedure?

https://docs.coveo.com/en/1616/cloud-v2-administrators/add-or-edit-an-amazon-s3-source#add-or-edit-an-amazon-s3-source